# Class Templates: Order of Construction

Tags: c++, templates, constructor

```
template < class T1, class T2 >
class A
{
    T1 x;
    T2 y;

  public:
    A(T1 a, T2 b)
    {
        x = a;
        y = b;
        cout << x << " " << y << endl;
    }

    A(T2 b, T1 a)
    {
        x = a;      
        y = b;      
        cout << x << " " << y << endl;
    } 
};

int main()
{
    A<int, float> obj1(1, 2.5);
    A<float, int> obj2(1, 2.5);

    return 0;
}
```

I understand why obj1 called the first constructor, but why is the second constructor called when obj2 is instantiated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `T1` and `T2` are `float` and `int` respectively, so the constructors look like

```
   A (float a, int b ) // first

   A (int a, float b ) // second
```

The constructor arguments are `int` and `double` respectively. The second constructor provides a better match than the first.

Comment: How did you deduce that T1 is float and T2 is int? Aren't they the opposite?

Comment: @DMehta No, they aren't, because you said this: `A < float, int > obj2`

Comment: Exactly my point. In the second constructor, the first argument is of type T2 and the second is of type T1. Am I wrong somewhere?

Comment: @DMehta Yes, and you are passing `int` and `double`, so the second constructor is a better match. But that is what I said in the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but for some reason, I'm not able to understand this. Is there some literature which I can refer to?

Answer (score 0):

When the object obj1 of the class A is created, the instantiation:

```
A < int, float > obj1 ( 1, 2.5 )
```

tells the compiler that  `T1` should be treated as `int` and `T2` should be treated as `float`. Therefore, the object sees the two constructors as:

```
A ( int a, float b ) // first

A ( float a, int b ) //second
```

The initial values passed to the `obj1` are `(int)` 1 and `(double)` 2.5 and since constructor 1 seems to be a better match, it is executed.

Now when the object obj2 is created, the instantiation:

```
A < float, int > obj1 ( 1, 2.5 )
```

tells the compiler that  `T1` should be treated as `float` and `T2` should be treated as `int`. Therefore, the object sees the two constructors as:

```
A ( float a, int b ) // first

A ( int a, float b ) //second
```

The initial values passed to the `obj1` are `(int)` 1 and `(double)` 2.5 and since constructor 2 seems to be a better match, it is executed.